# Discord.py How do I delete a singular message in the rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to delete a singular message when triggered but I cannot figure it out. I got purge working with `await ctx.channel.purge` but that's not what I want since that requires an amount

The old version was written like `await self.bot.delete_message(ctx.message)` but that now brings the error `object has no attribute 'bot'`

Reading the documentation all I could find was `Message.delete` but that brings the error: `NameError: name 'Message' is not defined`

I am sure this is a simple solution but I cannot work it out. Thanks in advance

My current code is:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(self, ctx, *args):
   '''Make Bot repeat your messages'''
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await Message.delete(ctx.message)
    await ctx.send(mesg)`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about the message that triggered the command, then you can do:

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Oh wow I knew it was simple, but not that simple I cannot believe I missed the capitalization, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use await message.delete() to delete the trigger message
(for example, user sends !say hi, bot says hi, and it deletes the user's message "!say hi")
really late here but ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).